# How to restore permanently trash page?

Tags: posts, pages, trash

I have accidentally permanently deleted the home page from my website.

Is there any way how to restore it? :(

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to restore it is to restore a backup of your MySql database. Login to your web host and see if there are any backups of your database available. Then you can restore the backup and it will bring that content back. Make sure you haven't added any other content after the backup timestamp or else you will lose that. If you want to make a manual backup of your database, login to phpMyAdmin (via your hosting dashboard or cpanel) and then select your WordPress database and click the Export tab. Then do a quick export and it will download a .sql file to your computer which can be used as a backup to restore from.

Comment: It worked! Fortunately there is automatic backup on databases set up. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent! Can you please mark my answer as the correct answer if you don't mind? Thanks :)